# How do I toggle on and off sneak in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can you toggle between sneak and normal standing position?  It's kind of annoying having to keep a button pressed while I try to build and move around to get a better view of what I am doing.

Comment: Suggestion: change sneak to `Ctrl` and use `WASD` or `ESDF`, your pinky should be able to hold down the CTRL key without too much of an issue.

Comment: Changing sneak to CTRL just makes it harder to hit than SHIFT. That helps how?

Comment: Shift is more natural for my hand.  I thought there was a way to toggle.

Comment: I've started a vote on the minecraft forum for how a toggle crouch/sneak could be implemented. Feel free to come by and vote. If you add your thoughts to the comment area on the thread you can help keep the issue alive and get noticed (=

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While you're holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to sneak, press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key once. This will return control to your mouse pointer, and when you click on the game window again, you will be permanently crouched until you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> again.

This only works in windowed mode - there is currently no way to toggle crouch in fullscreen. Notch has, however, expressed interest in adding sneak toggle capability.

Comment: Also note that this "tap <kbd>Alt</kbd> key glitch" works on Windows, but may not work on Linux or Mac.

Comment: It will not keep the state when you open a chat window, or other UI interface in the game. So you cannot for example use this to allow you to chat while treading water. You need a mod for that (see my answer :))

Comment: It's just a window exploit for temporarily locked crouching, it's not meant to let you do things like simultaneously tread water and chat.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: this is no longer necessary as of 1.15, see [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/384220/106038) below

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a mod that does Toggle Sneak and MUCH MUCH more, and I plan on keeping it up to date with MC versions.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/355537-166-controlpack-autosneakrunsmartfurnacelookbehindlots-more-v21/

Comment: Does it keep sneaking when using furnace, workbench, or chatting?

Comment: Yup! Which also means you can chat while hanging onto a ladder. I recommend you check out the demo youtube video in the forum post.

Comment: @Infinities I've been using your mod for about a week now and it's fantastic. Thanks a bunch, man.

Comment: @Fambida Awesome, thanks! :) Always motivating to hear that.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to toggle sneaking in Minecraft. However, you could always tape down / weigh down your actual `Shift` key.

Answer (score 8):

As of 1.15+ there is an option to toggle sneak in the Accessibility Settings submenu in Options:

[image: Minecraft Accessibility Settings sneak toggle option location]

There is also a text list of these options with more details [on the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options#Accessibility_Settings) as well as the [source that this was added in 1.15](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options#History). I tested this option myself in 1.16.2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a mac you can simply set the crouch command to the caps-lock key. unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called AutoHotkey that can do stuff like this for windows.

Comment: Autohotkey is a large and complex program. This answer is useless without more information.

Comment: AHK isn't large or hard, but since you are having problems:  http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/dhvvn/how_to_toggle_sneak_for_windows/

Answer (score -2):

To toggle on and off just change your sneak to caps lock